# Create a draggable UIView on long press of a different view

Tags: ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I have implemented something that does the following:

I am showing a full-screen `UICollectionView` with different items.  Underneath this view (out of sight) is a "detail" view for one of the items.

When a user long-presses one of the `UICollectionView` items, I would like to hide the `UICollectionView` to reveal the "detail" view behind.

I will then instantiate a new `UIView` which is hovering over this view and is draggable.  The user can then drag and drop this new `UIView` into position on the "detail" screen.

The only part which I am having trouble with is the syncing of the long-press with the draggable view.  I would like the user to long-press on the `UICollectionView`, and then be immediately dragging the draggable view.

How do I connect these two actions?

At the moment the UICollectionView calls a delegate on the lower view, which instantiates the draggable view:

```
- (void)contactAlgorithm:(ContactAlgorithmViewController *)contactFlowViewController didLongPressContact:(CDContact *)contact {    
DraggableContactView *draggableView= [[DraggableContactView alloc] initWithContact:contact];
[self.view addSubview:draggableView.view];
```

}

But how do I make this draggable view the view which is being dragged by the long.press?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the frame of the item which was long pressed.
Add the draggable view at exactly that frame.

Now, add pan gesture recogniser to that view and set delegate of that gesture to viewController , and whenever move occurs delegate method will be called.
There change the frame of draggable view to follow touch.

Instead of adding pan gesture, you can use touchesMoved method of viewController.

**CODE:**
using below code, you can drag the view **without using pan gesture**.

```
//have a class property of DraggableContactView
@implementation ViewController{

    DraggableContactView *dragableView;
}
```

Selector method of longPressGestureRecogniser

```
-(void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)ges{

    if(dragableView==nil){
        dragableView=[[DraggableContactView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        dragableView.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];
        [self.view addSubview:dragableView];
    }
    CGPoint p =[ges locationInView:self.view];
    [dragableView setCenter:p];
}
```

Comment: Yes!  I have that all already.  I need to know how to connect the long-press on the custom view to the draggable UIView.  I've updated my answer above with the delegate code I'm using.

Comment: Thanks you santhu!  How do I "change the frame of the draggable view to follow touch"?

Comment: you can use locationInView of gesture to get point.and set that point as centre (setCentre)of draggable view.

Comment: AH OK!  So the draggable view is not being dragged!  It is just having its position updated whenever the touch moves on the gesture.  Ok!  Perfect.  Will try that now.  Thanks santhu!

Comment: A full example of how to do this using the pan gesture recognizer is here: http://weydev.com/en/drag-an-drop-uicollectionview/